# Application of Implementing 3 Stacks in single array

Tags: data-structures, stack, implementation

Well there is lot of discussion about implementing 3 [ or 2 stacks ] in a single array. but whats the **real need or application** for implementing stacks like that?

can't we allot memory as 3 seperate stacks [array] itself?. anyway we are alloting array[size * 3] in that single array.

[how-to-implement-3-stack-in-a-single-array-efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397344/how-to-implement-3-stack-in-a-single-array-)

Comment: in case of storing integers it's easier to use 3 stacks instead of just 1, but when you have a stack of objects, the size of a pointer is much less than the size of an object-clone

Comment: @KhaledAKhunaifer: I'm a beginner. can you explain elaborately.

Comment: `int` is a primitive data type that consume memory space of `4 bytes`, an `object` of `class { int, int, int }` would consume `3 * 4 = 12 bytes`; the size of a `pointer` in `C\C++` is `4 bytes`; in the case of integers, we have `4 = 4` so it's not difference .. but in case of objects (as the example) we have `4 < 12` thus it's more efficient to store 3 stacks of the same values using a single one

Comment: The 3 stacks are the same, but they differ in how items are ordered